# Django admin raw_id_fields description is not changing

Tags: django, django-admin

In my admin site I have a model:

```
class PatientMedAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = (
        'icd_10',
    )
```

And it appears this way:
[image]

When I change the value using the magnifying glass the ID is changing but the description is not.
The description is changing only when I save me form.
I have installed these additional apps: [admin_view_permission](https://github.com/ctxis/django-admin-view-permission), [django_extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions).
Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v found this [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7028#no1). It looks like this is an usual behavior. I thing I will use Grapelli or something like that to avoid it.